# How to determine order for new item?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a members table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE  `members` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(65) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `order` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I would like to let users order the members how they like.
I'm storing the order in `order` column.

I'm wondering how to insert new user to be added to the bottom of the list.
This is what I have today:

```
$db->query('insert into members VALUES (0, "new member", 0)');
$lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
$maxOrder = $db->fetchAll('select MAX(`order`) max_order FROM members');
$db->query('update members 
            SET 
                `order` = ?
            WHERE 
                 id = ?', 
           array(
               $maxOrder[0]['max_order'] + 1, 
               $lastId
        ));
```

But that's not really precise while when there are several users adding new members at the same time, it might happen the `MAX(order)` will return the same values.

How do you handle such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the SELECT as part of the INSERT, such as:

```
INSERT INTO members SELECT 0, "new member", max(`order`)+1 FROM members;
```

Keep in mind that you are going to want to have an index on the `order` column to make the SELECT part optimized.

In addition, you might want to reconsider the tinyint for order, unless you only expect to only have 255 orders ever.

Also order is a reserved word and you will always need to write it as `order`, so you might consider renaming that column as well.

Comment: backticks are how you escape field names in mysql - he's done it right in the examples.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already automatically increment the id for each new member, you can order by id.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand. If each user wants a different order how will you store individual user preferences in one single field in the "members" table?

Usually you just let users to order based on the natural order of the fields. What is the purpose of the order field?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I make all my select statements order by "order, name"; Then I always insert the same value for Order (either 0 or 9999999 depending on if I want them first or last).  Then the user can reorder however they like.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent having 2 items with the same `order` values if inserted at the same time.
I'm inserting item with `order` being '0' and then try to find new `order` value which is not already taken, but if 2 users do it simultaneously, I will end up with 2 equal values

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB supports transactions. Before the insert do a 'begin' statement and when your finished do a commit. See [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171) for an explanation of transactions in mySql.

Comment: Transactions are fine, but still you are not preventing from having 2 items with the same `order` as we have only one select and one update query.
Transactions would help in different cases, when you do several inserts/updates...

Comment: You are completely right. My answer does not solve your problem. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a table with keys (member_id,position) that maps to another member_id. Then you can store the ordering in that table separate from the member list itself. (Each member retains their own list ordering, which is what I assume you want...?)

Supposing that you have a member table like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| member_id | name         |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 | John Smith   |
|         2 | John Doe     |
|         3 | John Johnson |
|         4 | Sue Someone  |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Then, you could have an ordering table like this:

```
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
| member_id_key | position | member_id_value |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
|             1 |        1 |               4 |
|             1 |        2 |               1 |
|             1 |        3 |               3 |
|             1 |        4 |               2 |
|             2 |        2 |               1 |
|             2 |        3 |               2 |
+---------------+----------+-----------------+
```

You can select the member list given the stored order by using an inner join. For example:

```
SELECT name
FROM members inner join orderings 
  ON members.member_id = orderings.member_id_value
WHERE orderings.member_id_key = <ID for member you want to lookup>
ORDER BY position;
```

As an example, the result of running this query for John Smith's list (ie, WHERE member_id_key = 1) would be:

```
+--------------+
| name         |
+--------------+
| Sue Someone  |
| John Smith   |
| John Johnson |
| John Doe     |
+--------------+
```

You can calculate position for adding to the bottom of the list by adding one to the max position value for a given id.